# RTC for Riverdi STM32 Embedded Display RVT70HSSFWCA0 not running when power is off

Tags: embedded, stm32, real-time-clock, stm32h7

Good day, I have recently implemented a RTC function to be displayed on my Riverdi STM32 Embedded Display RVT70HSSFWCA0 using TouchGFX. the project works well and it shows the RTC value on the display like date and time. it also stores the data when power off so no problem there. However, the RTC does not run when the power to my Display is turned off even though I have placed a battery for it that has 3 Volts.

I tried checking the battery to see if that was the issue or the connector, both were working fine and giving 3 Volts. I thought it would be the battery fault like it has run out of charge but it wasn't.  Can someone help me fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: is there a microcontroller between the RTC and the display? And is that one powered by the battery as well?

Comment: This sounds like a question for electronics.stackexchange.com.  Be sure to include the schematic.

Comment: This sounds like a question you really should ask Riverdi first. Otherwise, if you want to post it as a general STM32 question, treat it as such, i.e. post relevant portions of schematics and relevant portions of code. As the first question, what's the source RTC clock? (Hint: only LSE works in VBAT mode.) Also, what exactly _RTC does not run_ means and how are you detecting that?

Answer (score 0):

Good day. I have contacted Riverdi through their E-Mail as they do not have any forums. I received an answer stating that currently their boards do not allow the RTC to run via the battery due to the LSE not being available to use for the RTC. They said that they are working on a fix for their newer boards but it will be some time before they are available to be purchased. Thank you all for your time and assistance Best Regards.

[Screenshot of the Email they sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2f8t.png)